# Need to remove permission on Sub-Folders for group programmatically

Tags: development, permissions, splistitem

I am struggling to remove subfolders permissions for a specific group. 
I've been on internet and of all the solutions I keep getting the error

> Object does not belong to a list

Here is my code below:

```
SPFolder folder = _web.GetFolder(_url + "/" + folderName);
if(folder.Exists)
{                 
    SPPrincipal principal = (SPPrincipal)_group;
    SPRoleAssignment rAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(_group);                     

    folder.Item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
    folder.Item.RoleAssignments.Remove(principal);
    folder.Item.Update();
}
```

Comment: What is the folder you are trying to break permissions on? In a list or library I persume?

Comment: It's on a List from a subsite

Comment: so `_web` is a subweb?

Comment: Yes it is a sub web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user below code getting group and then remove it after breaking permission. Hope this helps.

```
SPFolder folder = _web.GetFolder(_url + "/" + folderName);
if(folder.Exists)
{                                   
    SPPrincipal pri = folder.Item.RoleAssignments.Groups["GroupName"];

    folder.Item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
    folder.Item.RoleAssignments.Remove(pri);
    folder.Item.Update();
}
```

Comment: OK I saw the what was the problem when I was requesting the url I didn't include the .url. Now that is correct and I am getting the "value does not fall within the expected range" from the GetFolder Method.

Comment: What is the url that you are providing ? like Application/sites/subsite/Lists/listname. I guess you are having difficulty in getting folder.

Comment: Yes and the folderName has a dash like "WHATEVER-THIS"

Comment: Folder name should not be a problem. as you are giving folder name as string. Are you still getting error ? Can you share your URL which you are giving and foldername I got "WHATEVER-THIS"

Comment: The foldername should be .......RootFolder=%2fdvdmarketing%2fElementsLibrary%2fSDFDFDFD&Folder

Comment: Whatever name you gave like "WHATEVER-THIS" . This should be folder name.